# Trying to figure out arrays in VB

Tags: vb.net

So basically I am trying to get to this:

[image]

and am having trouble with a few things. Firstly, I want to be able to enter the year and have everything work out properly but am unsure of how I can go about doing that. I also need to be able to calculate the total of each year, and then the total for all of the years.

I am very new to arrays and any help would be much appreciated.

```
Public Class Form1

    'Set values for the quaters
    Dim quater() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4}
    Dim salesbox(3, 11) As Decimal
    Dim total() As Decimal = {0}
    Dim Yearss() As Integer = {1999, 2000, 2001, 2002}


    'Simple sub to show the headings on the list box
    Sub showtitles()

        Dim message As String
        OutBox.Items.Clear()

        message = "Year" & ControlChars.Tab &
              "Q1" & ControlChars.Tab &
              "Q2" & ControlChars.Tab &
              "Q3" & ControlChars.Tab &
              "Q4" & ControlChars.Tab &
              "Total" & ControlChars.Tab

        OutBox.Items.Add(message)
    End Sub

    'Input for that quater/sales for that quater/year
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim getQ As Integer
        Dim getsales As Decimal
        Dim message As String
        Dim getyear As String

        message = "Enter Quater"
        getQ = InputBox(message) - 1

        message = "Enter sales for Quater"
        getsales = InputBox(message)

        message = "Enter year"
        getyear = InputBox(message) - 1

        salesbox(getyear, getQ) += getsales

    End Sub
```

Ok so for this part I can get the numbers to go in the correct positions, but only for these default values on the year of 1-4.

For some reason I just cannot figure out how to input the year and have it shot up under year on the output box

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Message As String
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim column As Integer

    Call showtitles()
    For row = 0 To 3 Step 1
        Message = quater(row) & ControlChars.Tab
        For column = 0 To 6 Step 1
            Message += FormatCurrency(salesbox(row, column)) & ControlChars.Tab

        Next
        OutBox.Items.Add(Message)
    Next
    For column = 0 To 1 Step 1
        Message = Yearss(column)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you displaying the numbers on-screen? Are you using manually-positioned `Label` controls or something similar? Have you considered using a `DataGridView` instead? (I assume this is WinForms)

Comment: Oh, I see, you're using `Tab` and whitespace characters to attempt to arrange things into almost a table format inside a single `Label`. You should avoid this because characters are not monospace. You should use a `DataGridView` instead.

Comment: If you can use DataTable, it will be much easier.